# Google Sheets : Condition to copy something on another cellule

Tags: google-sheets

For my job I want to Automatize some easy fonction for someone who don't know how to work with Sheets so for the moment i want to do that :
**If A2 have "ok" so B2 will copy C2 number**.
Can we do that on google sheets?
I already test something but not working.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try in B2:

```
=IF(A2="ok"; C2; )
```